# I want to remove a line in a text file by asking the user to input an attribute in the line to delete it

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I have a txt file with ID's, student names and other attributes. I am asked to give the user the option to delete a studetn from the file by asking them to input their ID or their name only. Any ideas?

```
   ID    Name
```

e.g. ['102', 'Michael jackson', '3', '54', '30', '84']

```
def getlist():
    fp = open("student.txt", "r")
    list = fp.readlines()
    for i in range(len(list)):
        list[i] = list[i].split(";")
    return list

print("removing Students from the class based on")
        print("1-ID\t2-Student Name")
        fp=open("student.txt","r")
        
        list = getlist()
        c=int(input("Enter your choice:"))
        if(c==1):
            a=int(input("Enter the ID to remove:"))
            for i in range(1,len(list)):
                    if a==int(list[i][0]):
                        list.remove(list[i])
        else:
            b=input("Enter the Student name to remove")
            print("Records found under the name"+"("+b+")")
            for i in range(len(list)):
                if b==list[i][1]:
                    print(list[i],end=" ")
                    print("\n")

            ####this is for students with the same name
            z=int(input("Please select which record ID to remove:"))    
            
            for i in range(1,len(list)):
                #print(i)
                if z==int(list[i][0]):
                    list.remove(list[i])
                    break
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

Your project is almost done. You only need to create a function to save the file.

Comments:

- Rename `getlist` to `load_records`. "get" is for something immediate; "load" is when you fetch something anew. Rename "list" to "records" (or "pupils", or "db"), as it's more descriptive (naming a variable "list" in Python is not a good idea anyway, as it's a name of a built-in function).
- Rename `a`, `b`, `z` to `name`, `id`.
- Have `save_records` too.
- Try not to use the style `for i in range(len(list))` if you can.

E.g., instead of:

```
list = fp.readlines()
for i in range(len(list)):
    list[i] = list[i].split(";")
return list
```

do:

```
list = []
for line in fp:
    list.append(line.split(';'))
return list
```

(More experienced programmers would write that function as:

```
def load_records():
    with open("student.txt") as f:
        return [ line.split(';') for line in f ]
```

)

- Similarly, instead of:

  ```
        for i in range(len(list)):
            if b==list[i][1]:
                print(list[i],end=" ")
                print("\n")
  ```

Do:

```
        for rec in records:
            if b == rec[1]:
                print(rec, end=" ")
                print("\n")
```

(Experienced programmers would just write `print([ rec for rec in records if rec[1] == b ])`.)

- You duplicate the code that deletes a record. That's not good. Move the code that deletes a record (by ID) to a separate function.